# Presenting Areas of Land from shapefile to 1 decimal position and convert from m-squared to hactares

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling

I've got a shapefile containing multiple polygons, attached to an attribute table. I'm looking at labeling all these polygons using the attribute 'AREA' column. However, these areas have not been rounded off and are in meters squared whereas I need them to be in Hectares. How would I convert these into hectares then present as a label.

Also, how can I create a white background for these labels?

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

Comment: you don't need to re-calculate the field. just display it in hectare with rounding.

Comment: use a label expression to calculate the labe from 2m to hect

Answer (score 0):

In your label Expression enter the following:

```vbs
round([AREA]/10000, 2)
```

This will convert your area from meters to hectares, and round it to two decimal places.  If you want more or less decimal places, just modify the `2` to the number of decimals you want on your label.